# Can Apache Solr output HTML instead of XML?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr

The question is simple - we have a sample / test Solr app running that only responds with XML right now. Is there an easy way to change that output to HTML? Running Tomcat as the app server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do XSLT transformations. There are a few samples built in I believe... check out http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltResponseWriter

Comment: Wow. Possibly right on target. I will look into this and post back :)

Comment: Turns out that is a lot more complicated to implement than we had hoped. Exploring the solution Mauricio suggested...

Answer (score 3):

Check out [VelocityResponseWriter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter) (aka Solritas) which uses [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) templates to generate output. It's substantially easier to use than XSLT.

Here's an [introduction](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/11/04/solritas-solr-1-4s-hidden-gem/).